# How to add an object to other object in c#

Tags: c#

I'm making school degree program as a practice by myself.
But I wanna add degree object to program object which is more wider concept than degree in order to execute one line to implement this program. 
(I have further idea about this program but a basic concept what I want to know is this question)

For instance, I coded like below

```
namespace Mod1_SelfAssesment
{
    public class UniProgram
    {
        public string Programme { get; set; }

        public UniProgram(string programme)
        {
            this.Programme = programme;
        }

        Degree master = new Degree("Master");
    }
}

namespace Mod1_SelfAssesment
{
    public class Degree
    {
        public string _Degree { get; set; }
        public Degree(string degree)
        {
            this._Degree = degree;
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, I have to instantiate two class in Main method and this is not what I want to execute. And, "code Degree master = new Degree("Master");" in UniProgram class doesn't have any usage here.

Would u please help me about this?

Thank u in advance~!!

Comment: You need to make your question clearer, although that is hard when you are a newb! Are you saying that every UniProgram must have a Degree (use Constructor) or that a UniProgram can have zero or more degrees, in which case you need to introduce a collection to UniProgram and allow external clients to add Degree instances to the collection.

Comment: A university program can earn a student multiple degrees, but right now there can be only one.  Google "c# how to create a collection class" to get ahead.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you intend to do, then you'll need a `List<Degree> master` to be able to store multiple master degrees.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following correctly...

```
namespace Mod1_SelfAssesment
{
public class UniProgram
{
  public string Programme { get; set; }
  public IList<Degree> Degrees {get;set;}

public UniProgram(string programme)
{
    this.Programme = programme;
    Degrees = new List<Degree>();
}



 namespace Mod1_SelfAssesment
 {
   public class Degree
   {
    public string _Degree { get; set; }
    public Degree(string degree)
    {
        this._Degree = degree;
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to make `Degree` a property of the `UniProgram`. If so, you can add an additional constructor (chaining them) so that in one line you define both.

```
public class UniProgram
{
    public string Programme { get; set; }
    public Degree Degree { get; set; }

    public UniProgram(string programme)
    {
        this.Programme = programme;
    }

    // Second constructor so you can also define degree
    // : this(...) allows you to call other constructor so either can be used
    public UniProgram(string programme, string degree) : this (programme)
    {
        this.Degree = new Degree(degree);
    }

}
```

Now you can use the program in 2 ways

```
// Usage example
var program = new UniProgram("Program without degree");
var programWithDegree = new UniProgram("Program with degree", "Master");
```

Based on comments, if your program allows for multiple degrees, you might consider what other answer provides. This is another way to do that.

```
public class UniProgram
{
    public string Programme { get; set; }
    public IList<Degree> Degrees { get; } = new List<Degree>();

    public UniProgram(string programme, params string[] degree)
    {
        this.Programme = programme;
        foreach (var name in degree)
            this.Degrees.Add(new Degree(name));
    }

}
```

Then you can use this object like this:

```
// Additional usage scenarios
var programMultiple = new UniProgram("Multiple degrees", "Master", "Doctorate");
programMultiple.Degrees.Add("Another degree"); // You can also add degrees any time later
```

To learn more about the code above/features used above:

- Parameter Array: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params
- Collections/Lists: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx
- Properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties
- Constructors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors

Comment: Thank u. I think your way is right. By the way, what is the role " : this (programme)" next to second constructor? is this indicating a parameter of first constructor? what if I don't use the " : this..."?

Comment: ah~~ I understand by myself. Thanks a lot~!